# Tiktok API scraping

Tags: python, tiktok, rapidapi

I have been working on Tiktok scraping lately but I want to scrap a field which would give me average watch time of a particular video. Is there any field like that or any other field which gives same data. thankyou in advance.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you tagged **rapidapi** you try to scrape average watch time unlogged or via a tiktok bot user that is not the owner of the video.

This is not possible with such tools and you need to find a tool that takes the cookies of the video uploader, that has the functionality to check video info. As of today, I [haven't seen any such API](https://rapidapi.com/search/tiktok) that takes your cookies on RapidAPI.

Another approach would be to use API's that sign your requests to TikTok and approach it with a custom solution by yourself.